# About use of underscore, or not, at the same class attribute in Python

Tags: python, attributes

Why in this example, sometimes the author use `self._temperature` and 
`self.temperature` (with and without underscores) for the same attribute ?

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value
```

Comment: They are not the same attribute. They are different attributes. `temperature` is actually a class attribute which is a  `property`, and `_temperature` is a "private" instance attribute.

Comment: Also, the author should have used `self.temperature = temperature` in `__init__` instead of `self._temperature = temperature`. Essentially, `property` is (one) way in which Python programmers use *encapsulation*, instead of using regular getter and setter methods. Read the following: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php however, disregard their use of double-underscore name-mangling for "private" variables, you should just use a single underscore

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. But where is the class attribute declared?

Comment: Right here:`def temperature(self):`. Note, class attributes and instance attributes are different things. One belongs to the class, the other to the instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate attributes in use here. `_temperature` is an *instance* attribute, while `temperature` is a *class* attribute, whose value is a `property` object. Accessing `temperature` triggers a method call which acts upon the instance variable `_temperature`.

The use of the underscore indicates something is "private", and should not be accessed directly. It is a common convention for the name of the attribute backing a property to be the name of the property prefixed with a `_`.

Comment: Where is declared the class attribute "temperature"?

Comment: Technically, *everything* defined at the top level of a `class` statement is a class attribute. `_temperature`, though, is not; it's only defined *inside* a method.

Comment: `@property def temperature(self):...` defines the attribute, and `@temperature.setter` creates a *new*, augmented `property` object that replaces the one previously bound to `temperature`.